# I am working on a calculator in Visual Studio. I cannot get the Mod function button right

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am working on a calculator that has the function buttons. I have already gotten the Cos, Sin, Tan buttons to work. I am failing in the Mod function button area. I keep getting an error code of 'System.Math' does not contain a definition for 'Mod'. This is what I am inputting:

```
private void ModButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  FirstNumber = Convert.ToDouble(DisplayTextBox.Text);  // you need to read in the number in the DisplayTextBox and convert it to Double
  FirstNumber = Math.Mod(FirstNumber);
  DisplayTextBox.Text = FirstNumber.ToString();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no Math.Mod() method, just like the error message says.  There's no Math.Add() method either.  To add you use the + operator.  Use the % operator for mod.  It takes two operands, just like add.  In other words, you calculate a + b and a % b.  The ones you done only take one operand, like sin(a).

Comment: Could you clarify a little bit. Two operands?

Comment: @Lynda Means it takes two arguments. Addition requires two numbers, sin takes 1.

Answer (score 2):

The modulo function takes two arguments, the dividend and the divisor, just like the normal division function. In C#, the `%` operator is modulo division. So,

`int a = b % c;`

Is what you're after. Like Visual Studio and the comments say, there is no `Math.Mod` function.

In the above snippet, `b` is the dividend and `c` is the divisor. `9 % 5` is 4 because there is 4 left over after dividing 9 by 5.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it now. Was having a brain stuck moment.

Comment: @Lynda you should accept the answer as soon as possible. [You can accept an answer after 15 minutes of asking the question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)